# datetime and timezones in a RESTfull mysql server running on node.js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, datetime, amazon-ec2, sails.js

I have a RESTfull server with a Mysql DB and node.js running in an Amazon ec2 instance located in Frankfurt, one table has a date time field showing

> 2017-05-25 00:00:00

When I ask the server for all dates inside an interval I get back that record in this way:

> Fri May 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Why is this happening ? 
How can I fix it to receive the same datetime as written in the database no matter of what is my local time?

EDIT

On client side, I'm using a $resource method inside an angular service, and with the GET method I query all records inside a specific date interval like this:

```
      Get:function(){
          var firstDayOfThisWeek = moment($rootScope.newDate).startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' 00:00:00:00';
          var lastDayOfThisWeek = firstDayOfThisWeek.clone().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' 00:00:00:00';
          var allBookings = $resource(IP_ADDRESSES.dbserver+'bookings');

          return  allBookings.query({where:{or:[
                    {departure: {'>': firstDayOfThisWeek, '<=': lastDayOfThisWeek}},
                    {arrival:{'>=':firstDayOfThisWeek, '<=':lastDayOfThisWeek}},
                    {arrival:{'<=':firstDayOfThisWeek}, departure:{'>=': lastDayOfThisWeek}},

                ]}}).$promise;
            }
```

On Server side I use Sails.js with the default configuration, and the mysql Waterline adapter. The controller is empty (default blueprint is answering to all request made in a RESTfull manner).
This is the model:

```
module.exports = {

tableName: 'bookings',
adapter: 'mysql',
autoCreatedAt: true,
autoUpdatedAt: true,

attributes: {

  id: {type: 'integer',autoIncrement: true,primaryKey: true,unique:true},
  booking_n: {type: 'integer'},
  customer: { model:'customers'},
  room: {type: 'string'},
  guest: {type: 'string'},
  guests_n: {type:'integer'},
  arrival: {type: 'date'},
  departure: {type: 'date'},
  confirmed: {type: 'integer'},
  agent: {type: 'string'},
  price: {type: 'float'},
  deposit: {type: 'integer'},
  notes: { type: 'string'},
  refundable: {type: 'integer'},
  createdAt: {type: 'date'},
  updatedAt: {type: 'date'},
  invoice:{model:'invoices'}
 }
};
```

This is what I get from the chrome console:

[image]

The SPA and the RESFull server are hosted in 2 different EC2 instances.

EDIT 2

Grabbing the query with POSTMAN interceptor and sending back the same exact query with POSTMAN I get this result

> "id": 7872,
>       "booking_n": 1462556458407,
>       "arrival": "2017-05-25T22:00:00.000Z",
>       "departure": "2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z",
>       "confirmed": 1,
>       "agent": "Expedia.com",
>       "createdAt": "2016-05-06T17:40:58.000Z",
>       "updatedAt": "2016-05-06T17:42:29.000Z",
>       etc etc

In my opinion this is a TMZ issue, and I would like to know what is the best practice to approach this problem.

Comment: It is happening because of the non-shown-by-you method you are using? :p

Comment: @Drew, pretty much standard methods. Angular.js $resource query on client side and sails.js with default blueprints on top of the node server. But I will be more specific later on, because at the moment I'm traveling.

Comment: @Drew, I think I've wrote down all information I have.But if you need more clarifications, feel free to ask.